# USB 3.0 external HDD recognized as 2.0

Tags: usb, external-hdd

System: ACER Aspire 5830TG

USB 2.0 x3; USB 3.0 x1

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic

$ uname -r
4.18.0-10-generic
```

The HDD works fine as USB 3.0 with Windows on another system, which is ACER Aspire 5830TG too.

I do plug the HDD to USB 3.0 port. It is the only port which is blue and have additional pins. Nevertheless it looks like nothing is connected to USB 3.0 port, but the HDD (at least mechanically) is.

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 39, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 36, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 36, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 29, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 53, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 53, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

`$ lsusb -v` output for the HDD in question:

```
Bus 003 Device 039: ID 1058:0822 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1058 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0822 
  bcdDevice           10.07
  iManufacturer           1 Western Digital
  iProduct                2 My Passport 0822
  iSerial                 5 575836314141335931393130
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 USB Mass Storage
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              6 MSC Bulk-Only Transport
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           22
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat          32 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

So, the question is: Why is it so, and how do I (re)connect the HDD as USB 3.0?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL. Please update to a supported version of Ubuntu (18.04 or 19.10)

Comment: Thank you, but the system has lots of stuff installed and configured. If something goes wrong with the upgrade I  will face a lot of trouble. If this is the only suggestion I better leave it as it is. But maybe there is more specific solution.

Comment: You likely have a hardware fault, either in the USB to HDD external interface (most likely), in the ACER (less likely), or your Aspire does not support USB 3.0 under Linux. Many ASMEDIA USB3 chipsets only work under Windows because they require a driver not available for Linux. 1) Please troubleshoot further. Does this external USB-HDD combo work as USB3 on another PC? 2) Does any other drive rated USB 3.0 appear as USB 3.0 in the Acer? Please advise. Also, you can test by booting from an Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.10 LiveUSB which bypasses our prohibition in working on EOL versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Simple reboot solved the problem for now. I waited for some time for the bug to reproduce, but until now it did not happen again. On the other hand, before I wrote the post, I noticed problems with speed of HDD plugged to that 3.0 port several times, but did not dig deeper. So I continue the observations.